# Answer titles too big and cut off in post feedback

Tags: bug, design, 10k-tools, post-feedback

In the [post feedback 10k tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/most-helpful?filter=all), answer titles are big and cut off (but questions look ok):

> [image: image of bug]

On sites that use a serif font, answer titles also [stick out](https://english.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/most-helpful?filter=all) for being sans serif.

I’m also noticing it [elsewhere](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/annotated-posts?tab=noticed), but hopefully fixing it in one place fixes it everywhere.

This is in iPhone SE Safari, which has a very narrow screen, but I suspect it can be reproduced on any narrow browser window.

Comment: I can't reproduce on MSE, since i don't have 10k, but i try it on SO and i can there :P